# DCM4CHE Tools, dcmqrscp and movescu

Tags: java, dcm4che

Hi I'm trying to make a PACS server using java. I'm very new to pacs, dicom and the library dcm4che. I couldn't find a proper tutorial or examples so i cloned the whole project from github and examine dcmqrscp tool. But i've few troubles with it.

**Tools**

First of all i start dcmqrscp with following parameters, i can successfully use and save dcm file with storescu

```
dcmqrscp -b c0@localhost:26100 -dicomdir D:\dcmqrscp\dcmdir
```

But when i run movescu server throws java.net.ConnectException. These are my start parameters.

```
movescu -c c0@localhost:26100 -m StudyInstanceUID=1.2.840.113619.2.30.1.1762295590.1623.978668949.886 --dest STORESCP
```

What am i missing here?

Here's my cmd screens.
[image: dcmqrscp - 1]

[image: dcmqrscp - 2]

[image: movescu - 1]

[image: movescu - 2]

Comment: Where are you moving the study to? You connect to your PACS (via the movescu tool) and point to another (the STORESCP parameter you provided), but I don't see any details about that particular server.
An issued MOVE from your movescu client instructs your PACS (server) to STORE to another server (in this case the one identified by STORESCP). Also that server need to be known by your PACS (server) as STORESCP. 
My immediate diagnosis of your problem is that you only work with one server-node and thus cannot issue a MOVE command, but I may be mistaken :)

Comment: As an aside; the notion of SCP and SCU as it relates to the concepts of 'server' and 'client' may be a bit tricky! If you for instance communicate with a General Electric PACS and want to pull studies, your 'client' in the capacity of a SCU will need to issue a MOVE command to the GE PACS while at the same time and in the capacity of a SCP need to provide STORE functionality. Your MOVE command instructs the GE PACS (an SCP) to STORE studies to your client (acting as an SCP as well).
This is why it is more beneficial to discuss this in terms of SCU and SCP, rather than client and server.

Comment: Did this question get resolved?